# Changes on overloaded method behaviour between visual studio 2013 and 2015

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-2015, go-to-definition

Have have big problem with Visual Studio 2013 and 2015. In one class, i have defined this two methods:

1. `public List<T> LoadData<T>(string connectionStringName = "", string optWherePart = "", params object[] parameter)`
2. `public List<T> LoadData<T>(string optWherePart, params object[] parameter)`

I only want to call the second method like this:

`....LoadData<Config_Info>("ConfigName LIKE 'Version' AND UserName LIKE '' AND PlugInName Like ?", parameter: ProductName);`

If i go to definition in Visual Studio 2013, i come to the second method declaration, but in Visual Studio 2015, i come to the first. Both solutions are
absolutly identically.

Even the compiled result is different, so if i compile the same solution with VS 2015, the program stops working.

This is a very strange behaviour.

Does any one has an idea, what the differences are?

Comment: What's `ProductName`'s type?

Comment: I'ts a simple string.

Comment: OK, so I tried this at work on VS2010 and Go To Definition went to #2 (but I didn't run it so can't confirm which it calls.) I tried it at home on VS2015 and Go To Definition goes to #1 and Run goes to #1. I tried it at home on VS2013 and Go To Definition goes to #2 *and run goes to #2*. Either there's a bug in Intellisense in 2013 that 2015 fixed, or Roslyn is broken and somehow *installing 2015 broke the 2013 compiler but not Intellisense*.

Comment: Should i report some where? Thank you very much!

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/) I guess. I think this *is* a bug in the compiler; I'm about to write up an answer.

Comment: I've [submitted a bug](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/4424) based purely on the fact that I believe this behaviour doesn't conform to the spec. I can't tell whether it's a breaking change from 2010 but if it is it looks like the issue was with 2013, so not really Roslyn's fault.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is based on the C# 5 specification, but since the C# 6 specification doesn't appear to have been published yet that's the best I can do. It's also an attempt to invoke Cunningham's Law.

---

As a preliminary, in the language of s7.5.3.1 ("Applicable Function Member") of the spec, both function members are applicable (either of them could be called if the other didn't exist) in their expanded form (the `params object[]` can't be fulfilled by the `string` `ProductName` so is converted to an `object` argument).

Thus we move on to s7.5.3.2 ("Better Function Member") in order to decide which of the two is the better function to call.

---

Firstly, *a stripped-down argument list A is constructed containing just the argument expressions themselves in the order they appear in the original argument list*:

- `{ string "ConfigName [...]", string ProductName }`

Next, *[p]arameter lists for each of the candidate function members are constructed in the following way:*

- *The expanded form is used if the function member was applicable only in the expanded form.*
- *Optional parameters with no corresponding arguments are removed from the parameter list*
- *The parameters are reordered so that they occur at the same position as the corresponding argument in the argument list.*

This gives us the following:

- `{ string connectionStringName, object parameter }` (`optWherePart` removed, `params` expanded)
- `{ string optWherePart, object parameter }` (`params` expanded)

We then have a sequence of comparisons to make to decide which of these is the *better function member*. Calling one `Mp` and one `Mq`, these go as follows:

- *If `Mp` is a non-generic method and `Mq` is a generic method, then `Mp` is better than `Mq`.*

  - No difference here
- *Otherwise, if `Mp` is applicable in its normal form and `Mq` has a params array and is applicable only in its expanded form, then `Mp` is better than `Mq`.*

  - No difference here; both are in their expanded form
- *Otherwise, if `Mp` has more declared parameters than `Mq`, then `Mp` is better than `Mq`. This can occur if both methods have `params` arrays and are applicable only in their expanded forms.*

  - Not 100% on this one. Both our argument lists use 2 of the parameters from the original function definitions. I think this is *solely* meant to distinguish between one case where both arguments went into the same `params` array and one where one went into the array and one went into a normal argument.
- *Otherwise if all parameters of `Mp` have a corresponding argument whereas default arguments need to be substituted for at least one optional parameter in `Mq` then `Mp` is better than `Mq`.*

  - Aha! Our first argument list is missing `optWherePart`, which needed a default argument, so the second argument list is better! So VS2015 is wrong!

... but wait. What does this last bullet even mean? `Mp` and `Mq` are specifically parameter lists where *[o]ptional parameters with no corresponding arguments are removed*. There is no way either of them could not *have a corresponding argument* because if they didn't, they'd have been removed.

---

In conclusion, I can't tell whether this is a bug in the old compiler, the new compiler... or the C# specification.

I've found a [blog post](http://blog.slaks.net/2014-05-28/exploring-roslyn-part-3-breaking-changes/) by [SLaks](https://stackoverflow.com/users/34397/slaks) that also seems to think the old behaviour was a bug. The blog states that Roslyn had fixed this by making the compiler fail, and that's not what I see any more. Maybe they changed their minds?

---

Edit: Update! My [Roslyn bug report](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/4424) resulted in a [change to the compiler](https://github.com/Pilchie/roslyn/commit/ac28126a577d33ba369dcc42573311fbd5ce0dd5) to ensure that, in this case, the *second* overload is picked. This appears to be because of the *default arguments need to be substituted* wording above. I still think the spec is ambiguous, so I'm disappointed that only a code change was made (and not a spec change, or even a discussion about why the second overload is the better one), but at least the VS2015 runtime beaviour is now the same as it was in VS2013.

Comment: Can't Imagine a better answer! +1!